# I'm new in laravel and trying to build an app and its somehow stuck at the connection database cause I can't connect it in laravel 10

Tags: laravel, database

so I got this error

> could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `jobs` where `name` LIKE %% or `address` LIKE %%)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Job;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreJobRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateJobRequest;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class JobController extends Controller
{
    public function view($id) {
        
        $company = Company::find($id);
        //dd($company);
        $jobs = Job::where('company_id', '=', $id)->get();

        

        return view('users.view_company')->with(['jobs' => $jobs, 'company' => $company]);
    }

    public function viewInsertJob() {
        $company = Auth::user()->company;

        return view('company.insert_job')->with(['company' => $company]);
    }

    public function insert(Request $request) {
            // Validate the request data
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
            'jenis' => 'required|in:full-time,part-time,freelance',
            'gaji' => 'required|numeric',
        ]);

        // Create a new job post with the validated data
        $job = new Job;
        $job->name = $validatedData['name'];
        $job->detail = $validatedData['detail'];
        $job->address = $validatedData['address'];
        $job->gaji = $validatedData['gaji'];
        $job->jenis = $validatedData['jenis'];
        if(Auth::guest()){// Get the ID of the authenticated user
            return view('/login');
        }else{
            $job->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        }
        
        if ($job) {
            Alert::success('Success', 'anda berhasil mendaftarkan lowongan');
            $job->save();
            return redirect()->route('jobs.search');
            
        }
        else {
            Alert::error('Failed', 'gagal meregristrasi');
            return back();
        }
        // Redirect the user to the job post's page
        
    }
    public function edit(Job $job)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\UpdateJobRequest  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Job  $job
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateJobRequest $request, Job $job)
    {
        //                                                  
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Job  $job           
     */                               
    public function destroy(Job $job)
    {
        //
    }
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $keyword = $request->input('keywords');
        $location = $request->input('address');
        // $jobs = DB::select('select * from jobs where name = :keyword or location = :location', ['keyword'=>$keyword,'location'=>$location]); 
        $jobs = job::where('name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%" )->orwhere('address','LIKE',"%{$location}%")->get();   
        return view('jobs.search',['jobs'=>$jobs]);
    }
}
```

This is the code for the controller.
I can run the migration and its not a problem but I can't store the data in the database and get the data from the database

I already tried clearing cache and config:cache but still not working already try composer dump can someone help me to fix this

Comment: try removing the Alert::success line and modify the redirect below this way: return redirect()->route('your.route')->with('success', 'your message.');. this should fix the insert side of the problem. to read the data i would use $jobs = Job::where('name', $keyword )->orWhere('address',$location)->get();
(capital J in Job and W in orWhere, and i would validate $keyword and $location)

Comment: how should I validate the keyword and location? as a string? I still don't understand how I should validate it.

Comment: already try to make the validation but still error its like this
``` $validatedData = $request->validate([
     'keywords' => 'required|string|max:255',
       'location' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
$keyword = $validatedData('keywords');
 $location = $validatedData('address');
        // $jobs = DB::select('select * from jobs where name = :keyword or location = :location', ['keyword'=>$keyword,'location'=>$location]); 
$jobs = Job::Where('name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%" )->orWhere('address','LIKE',"%{$location}%")->get();   
return view('jobs.search',['jobs'=>$jobs,]); ```

Comment: please try this query (i misinterpreted the query before):  Job::where('name','like','%'.$keyword.'%' )->orWhere('address','like','%'.$location.'%')->get();   with regard to validation that has to follow your logic.  However, does the insert work??

Comment: the connection is the 1 that is not working so it needs to get the pdo to connect it

Comment: can you show me the .env values for the database? more specifically DB_CONNECTION value

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
 here is my env db connection

Comment: the problem is on the php.ini file that i have multiple of in my computer

Comment: sorry i cannot really help you with php.ini/server configuration stuff as i am not that good. all i can say is that i use the standard env configuration same as you do (and i never touched the php.ini file).